# UIWebView on iOS 10 not respond data

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, ios10, nsurlrequest

I try to connect `UIWebView` with Server API

**Error:-**

> void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

**Code:-**

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

   NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://release.xyz.com/test/xyz.json?amount=%@&user_id=%d&app_id=%@&platform=1",_amountText, [[DatabaseHelperClass sharedInstance] getUserID], [AppDetails sharedInstance].applicationID];

    urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"%22"];
    urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{" withString:@"%7B"];
    urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}" withString:@"%7D"];
    urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\t" withString:@"%20"];
    urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"%20"];
    urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\r" withString:@"%20"];
    urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"%5C"];     // for backward slash
    urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@"%23"];

    NSLog(@"%@",urlString);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    [_paymentGetwayWebView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}


- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if([[[request URL].scheme lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"ios"]) {
        NSString *match = [[request URL].absoluteString lowercaseString];

        if ([match hasPrefix:@"ios:PaymentComplete".lowercaseString]) {
            NSString *decoded = match.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding;
            NSString *jsonStr = [decoded stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ios:PaymentComplete/" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, decoded.length)];

            NSError *error = nil;
            id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

            if(error == nil && jsonObject && [jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                [self.delegate OnlinePaymentComplete:jsonObject];
            }
            else {
                [self.delegate OnlinePaymentFail];
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            }

            return YES;
        }
        else if ([match hasPrefix:@"ios:PaymentFail".lowercaseString])
        {
            [self.delegate OnlinePaymentFail];
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

It worked in iOS9 though.

XCode log is as follows--the 'chmodding parent' and 'nw_connection_write_close' are new since this problem started occurring

```
2016-10-19 13:48:57.367518 2.0.15[3121:57494] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event Event mask: 0x800
2016-10-19 13:49:36.057387 2.0.15[3121:57494] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event Socket received CONNECTED event
2016-10-19 13:49:36.060228 2.0.15[3121:57494] [] nw_socket_setup_notsent_lowat Set TCP_NOTSENT_LOWAT(16384)
2016-10-19 13:49:36.061454 2.0.15[3121:57494] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_connected [21.1 104.24.102.54:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] Output protocol connected
2016-10-19 13:49:36.061 2.0.15[3121:48645] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
```